# Javascript Regex for letters and single inverted comma

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write regex [for javascript] which should allow zero or more letters and only single inverted comma.
valid values are:

```
per'
p'
'
```

invalid values are

```
''
'9
```

I tried with `/^[a-zA-Z']+$/` but it allows any number of inverted commas.
I modified it to `/^[a-zA-Z'?]+$/`. But it still is not working.

Comment: If you want to match a single apostrophe, then put a single apostrophe in your regexp.

Answer (score 0):

see demo here https://regex101.com/r/wZ7dR3/1

```
/^[a-zA-Z]*'[a-zA-Z]*$/gm
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a multiline list of values to validate, you will need to use `m` option, too, like this:

```
var re = /^[a-z]*'[a-z]*$/gmi; 
var str = 'per\'\np\'\n\'\n\'\'\n\'9\nX\'YZ\n9\' \'';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    // eg m[0] etc.
}
```

See [example here](https://regex101.com/r/tB4fZ7/1).

Answer (score 0):

you can try this, this may help

```
var string="string";
var regex=/^[a-zA-Z]*'[a-zA-Z]*$/;

var result=string.match(regex);

if(result)
{
//your code
}
```